# Changing The Encoding Type Of A C# File?

Tags: c#, encoding

I'm making an SVN patch for a .cs file and I'm having a little trouble.  After making the patch, all I can see in my text editor is a bunch of gobble-dee-goop.  A lot of unrecognized characters and all of that.  I'm wondering if there's a way to change the encoding type to fix this problem (so I can see and apply the patches).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio: (with that file active) File, Advanced Save Options

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have [Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/), it has various encoding switching options.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Joel's: [What every developer should know about Unicode.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) Although not a direct answer to your question, this is a helpful resource that addresses the what's and why's:)